# How to divide UITableView into three part like iOS Music App TableView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to divide `UITableView` into three part like iOS Music App's `TableView` like following image

[image]

I want to divide like above Image's `UITableView`.

How can i?

Comment: You need to put different subviews in a parent view... only the scrolling parts are the table view

Comment: The answer, like most of apple's magic, is to fake it.  Having multiple tableviews produces an absolutely abysmal frame-rate on iOS devices, so just position 3 labels at three fixed positions within the cell, then draw dividers in core graphics.

Comment: hehe.i don't know how to code it. could you please some code? :)

Answer (score 1):

> make custom cell, in that custom cell put one view having three
>   imageViews, set images in such a way that it look likes above design.
>   create 3 images for left,center, right.

leftImage must have border line at right side for looking it as vertical line & rightImage must have border line at left side for looking like it as vertical line or simply you create one center image having border at both side.

for horizontal line you can simply use default cell seperators. if not then set cell seperator
to none & design above 3 images having top or bottom border line .

you can simply design it through the storyboard and assign your custom cell filename to TableViewCell. you can design custom cell like the link given below in comments

Comment: A nice Tutorial on custom UITableViewCell http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/